Neo4j Python Driver Asynchronous Performance
I want to concurrently run query on neo4j python.
Using neo4j's python async driver, I ran a test to see the async driver performance using the code below:
import asyncio
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from neo4j import AsyncGraphDatabase
import time

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(...)
async_driver = AsyncGraphDatabase.driver(...)

async def async_execute():
    records, _, _ = await async_driver.execute_query("MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10000", database_="...")
    rec_list = [record for record in records]


async def async_time(n):
    start = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(*(async_execute() for _ in range(n)))
    end = time.time()
    return end - start


def normal_time(n):
    start = time.time()
    for _ in range(n):
        records, _, _ = driver.execute_query("MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10000", database_="...")
        rec_list = [record for record in records]
    end = time.time()
    return end - start


async def main():
    async_runtime = 0
    normal_runtime = 0
    total_run = 10

    for _ in range(total_run):
        async_runtime += await async_time(2)
        normal_runtime += normal_time(2)

    print(f"async_runtime = {async_runtime/total_run}")
    print(f"normal_runtime = {normal_runtime/total_run}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

However, the result does not go as I expected:
async_runtime = 7.239475727081299
normal_runtime = 4.628250503540039
I expect that async_runtime should be lesser than normal_runtime . What could be the cause of this?
The code above comes from me trying to follow the examples here: https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/concurrency/.
I know there is an example of async performance improvement shown: https://community.neo4j.com/t/bolt-getting-dramatically-slower-with-increased-usage/64913. But for some reason, I can not replicate the improvement over my queries.
Configurations:
% pip show neo4j
Name: neo4j
Version: 5.18.0

% neo4j --version
5.18.1

If it helps, I ran PROFILE MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10000.

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Plan      | Statement   | Version | Planner | Runtime   | Time | DbHits | Rows  | Memory (Bytes) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | ""      | "COST"  | "SLOTTED" | 1665 | 60001  | 10000 | 64             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Planner COST

Runtime SLOTTED

Runtime version 5.18

+-----------------+----+---------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| Operator        | Id | Details | Estimated Rows | Rows  | DB Hits | Memory (Bytes) | Page Cache Hits/Misses |
+-----------------+----+---------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +ProduceResults |  0 | n       |          10000 | 10000 |   50000 |              0 |                    0/0 |
| |               +----+---------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +Limit          |  1 | 10000   |          10000 | 10000 |       0 |                |                    0/0 |
| |               +----+---------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +AllNodesScan   |  2 | n       |          10000 | 10000 |   10001 |                |                    0/0 |
+-----------------+----+---------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+------------------------+

Total database accesses: 60001, total allocated memory: 64

10000 rows
ready to start consuming query after 447 ms, results consumed after another 1218 ms


It's because, each time in execute_query, it connects to database and it takes considerable time. If you pass the same session for each async test, then it takes less time than normal run.
And also, I'd like to point out that in PROFILE query you provided, you can see that query time is much more less than python results. That's because of 'connection' time and it causes much of the bottleneck.
Here is the edited code:
import asyncio
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from neo4j import AsyncGraphDatabase
import time

driver = GraphDatabase.driver('neo4j://localhost:7687',
                                            auth=('neo4j', '94BuJ2\h7i1+'))
async_driver = AsyncGraphDatabase.driver('neo4j://localhost:7687',
                                            auth=('neo4j', '94BuJ2\h7i1+'))

query = "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10000"

async def async_execute(session):
    print("Running async query")
    await session.run(query)
    print("Async completed.")


async def async_time(n):
    start = time.time()
    async with async_driver.session() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*(async_execute(session) for _ in range(n)))
    end = time.time()
    return end - start


def normal_time(n):
    start = time.time()
    for _ in range(n):
        with driver.session() as session:
            print("Running sync query.")
            session.run(query)
            print("Sync completed")
    end = time.time()
    return end - start


async def main():
    async_runtime = 0
    normal_runtime = 0
    session_run = 4
    total_run = 2

    for _ in range(total_run):
        print(f"Executing {_ + 1}. run.")
        async_runtime += await async_time(session_run)
        normal_runtime += normal_time(session_run)

    print(f"async_runtime = {async_runtime/total_run}")
    print(f"normal_runtime = {normal_runtime/total_run}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Here is the results:
async_runtime = 4.446352958679199
normal_runtime = 10.133142590522766

